# stop extjs TextField from accepting blanks and spaces

Tags: extjs

This is my textfield

```
siteNameField = new Ext.form.TextField({
id: 'siteNameField',
fieldLabel: 'Site Name',
maxLength: 50,
allowBlank: false,
anchor:'-15',
xtype:'textfield',
maskRe: /([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)$/
```

});

As you can see it already has a check for blanks. But text field accepts space and I don't want that. I want no blank fields ... anything other than 'ONLY' spaces is acceptable .

Here is the FormPanel Code

```
voiceSiteCreateForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
    labelAlign: 'top',
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px',
    width: 600,        
    items: [{
        layout:'column',
        border:false,
        items:[{
            columnWidth:0.5,
            layout: 'form',
            border:false,
            //items: [siteNameField, siteNumberField,queueNameField,notifyFreqField,notifyStatusField]
            items: [siteNameField, siteNumberField]
        }]
    }],
buttons: [{
  text: 'Save and Close',
  handler: createSite
},{
  text: 'Cancel',
  handler: function(){
    // because of the global vars, we can only instantiate one window... so let's just hide it.
    siteCreateWindow.hide();
  }
}]
});
```

Please help,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove maskRe and use regex. Eg:

```
siteNameField = new Ext.form.TextField({
  id: 'siteNameField',
  fieldLabel: 'Site Name',
  maxLength: 50,
  allowBlank: false,
  anchor:'-15',
  xtype:'textfield',
  regex: /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/
});
```

Comment: There is still a problem 

This is the simple regex I use `regex:/[0-9]+/` and it accepts all kind of character .. How is that possible ... Secondly How can I show a custom message that may state something like "you can only insert numbers" on invalid data

Comment: OK I have done it using both regex and maskRe together like this 

  `siteNumberField = new Ext.form.TextField({
    id: 'siteNumberField',
    fieldLabel: 'Site Number',
    maxLength: 30,
    allowBlank: false,
    anchor:'-15',
 xtype:'textfield',   
    maskRe: /([0-9\s]+)$/ ,
 regex: /[0-9]/
  });`

maskRe doesn't let user insert anything other than numbers and regex doesn't validate spaces