# How to restrict the text field creation with only blankspaces?

Tags: extjs

I am facing a problem while text field creation, i.e I can create a field by using all  blank spaces. I have used `"allowblank:false"` but still its allowing only whitespaces. My textfield id is `Textfield_value`.

Comment: What do you really want to do? Do you want user to add some text in field before submitting the form?

Comment: Hi,i want to restrict the user creating a field by using only whitespaces..by entering spacebar morethan onetime which is inturn empty field but also textfield is allowing i.e my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got an answer to this question.

```
this. Field name.addListener({

            blur : function(){
                this.setValue(this.getValue().trim());
            }
        });
```

This trims the white spaces in the `textfield`

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you need that user should not be able to enter spaces in the text field. Please check out:

[stop extjs TextField from accepting blanks and spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517460/stop-extjs-textfield-from-accepting-blanks-and-spaces)

and here's another link that can be helpful for you.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?30790-TextField-AllowBlank-to-trim-spaces

Comment: With the link you provided is working but it too has an issue,when i click space bar one time its not showing any redmark,from second consecutive spacebar press its showing redmark...after that its working fine.i dont know why this abnormal behaviour

Comment: Hi wasimbhalli,Thanks for the help..its working fine.CAN you please tell how  to trim the spaces in the text field.